# heatmap.js clear existing map

Tags: javascript, heatmap

I'm using heatmap.js which can be found here:

http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/index.html

Anyways I've been able to create a heatmap successfully - now my problem is with resetting the data inside of an existing map - I want to clear it without creating a new object, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  All I know is how to set a data array, but I can't clear one.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's a built in way to do it, but you can use `.setDataSet` method and pass object with empty array of datapoints:

```
heatmap.store.setDataSet({data:[]});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ygalanter/UpbKH/2/**

Comment: I do not know if this answer has been verified to work or if it works for an older version, but I have the same issue as the OP and looking at the source code for heatmap.js it looks as if it will not clear but rather just ignore the empty array https://github.com/pa7/heatmap.js/blob/develop/build/heatmap.js#L142

Comment: OP's question is regarding v1.0 and the given answer works. If anyone else, like me, are using 2.0 this will not work. 2.0 is still in development so this might be fixed. Cheers

Comment: In heatmap.js v2.0.0 following code will work: `heatmap.setData({data:[]});`

Comment: @interstellarDust: That code is not working for me. Is there an updated version of that code?

Comment: @SandeepSilwal, I didn't work with this plugin for a while, can you show me your code, then may be I can help you.

Comment: In heatmap.js v2.0.5 this will work: `heatmap._renderer._clear();` Take note that this will only clear the canvas, not the dataset. It will continue to push in new data in case you are about to use `mousemove`.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who still wants an answer to this question.
I did not seem to find any direct method of clearing the map. The canvas that is used to draw the graph has a class name of "heatmap-canvas". So before you plot a new heatmap, run the following block of code to delete all previous heatmap canvas.

```
[...document.getElementsByClassName("heatmap-canvas")].forEach((e) =>
  e.remove()
);
```

Answer (score -1):

There is an in-built method `.clear()` that you can use

Comment: What is clear() a method for? Should it be heatmapLayer.clear() ?

Comment: the .clear() method does not specify which instance object to reference when calling it within the application.